# How do I make microphone input mono?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, alsa, microphone

I am using a USB-bluetooth microphone to do speech recognition with Google docs. The application says the sound is too soft but I have it turned up all the way. Is there any way in asoundrc to make the microphone register as mono rather than stereo? I think my sound is only coming in through one channel.

Someone told me this would do it but it looks like it affects outgoing as well as incoming.

pcm.makemono {

```
type route

slave.pcm "hw:2"

ttable {

    0.0 1    # in-channel 0, out-channel 0, 100% volume

    1.0 1    # in-channel 1, out-channel 0, 100% volume

}
```

}

Comment: If your sound is only coming in via one channel, then it is already mono.

Comment: The problem is that some applications use two channels anyway, in effect treating the mono mike as stereo input, and giving only half the volume. So perhaps what I want to do is force my "mono" mike to use the same sound in both channels.

Comment: You may need to disable one channel, as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/646724).  See also [in the Ubuntu Help  wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2FMicrophone_Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 3):

Adding a pulseaudio filter

```
M=$(pacmd list-sources | grep -P "name:.*alsa.*input" | tail -n 1 | perl -pe 's/.*<//g;s/>.*//g')
pacmd load-module module-remap-source source_name=mono master=$M master_channel_map=front-left,front-right  channel_map=mono,mono
```

and selecting the new default in settings worked for me.

Comment: It does make them both have the same input but they were still halved for me. I changed the second line to "...master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono..." and it was finally working properly.