# Microphone not working: remapping source to mono is not permanent

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 330 running Ubuntu 20.10 and the microphone doesn't work.

In my research, I've found that it's very common to have [mono microphone not working because the two channels are activated](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting#Line_Input.2FMicrophone_Troubleshooting). So I've just deactivated the right channel on Pavucontrol and it worked like a charm. Until the microphone auto adjusts the volume. When it happens, the right channel is activated again and set to the auto adjusted level.

I've already tried some solutions to deactivate microphone auto adjusment volume (which didn't work for me), but I'm looking for keeping auto adjustment activated while the right channel is deactivated. Is it possible?

**Edit:**

Because of suggestions, I tried to make input source mono, instead of stereo, like [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1039419). The answer suggests to use the `module-remap-source` command to remap one of the stereo channels to a new mono source:

```
M=$(pacmd list-sources | grep -P "name:.*alsa.*input" | tail -n 1 | perl -pe 's/.*<//g;s/>.*//g')
pacmd load-module module-remap-source source_name=mono master=$M master_channel_map=front-left  channel_map=mono
```

It works, but it's temporary. In an [ArchLinux troubleshooting wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting%23Auto-Mute_Mode#No_microphone_input_on_Acer_Aspire_One_and_Lenovo_Ideapad_310-15ISK/330-15ARR), I've found that I need to add the lines

```
load-module module-remap-source source_name=record_mono master=INPUT_NAME master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono
set-default-source record_mono
```

to the file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, in order to make the remap permanent and also make the source default. I restart PulseAudio and it works.

The problem comes when I restart my computer: it doesn't work automatically. I have to manually restart PulseAudio to changes take effect. Well, I could put a command in `crontab` to make PulseAudio restart after reboot, but it seems not to be a robust idea. At this point, I'm stuck in the same problem described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1271924/1033832). Both of us did a remap to make microphone mono, but it's not permanent.

Comment: What do you mean by "the microphone auto adjusts"?  If this is where things go wrong, you should dig deeper and figure out what exactly is happening

Comment: @Nmath It's known that microphone auto adjusts the volume. I've tested a couple of times: while monitoring the volume of the microphone, I record some of my voice, and the microphone volume is changes sometimes. It's expected in fact. I will edit the post to make it more clear.

Comment: Instead of deactivating a channel, can you set the input to mono?  As for the solutions you've tried that didn't work, if you can expand on that- what you tried and the response you got- this kind of diagnostic info sometimes helps figure it out

Comment: @Nmath, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to include my search for remapping the input source to mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pactl command in ~/.profile and just execute the remapping commands:

```
pactl load-module module-remap-source source_name=record_mono master=INPUT_NAME master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono
pactl set-default-source record_mono
```

If pulseaudio restarts at a later time then the string in default.pa will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems a good workaround is to add `pulseaudio -k` to `~/.profile`, so it's executed every time I login, as said in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1290592/1033832).